# How to access sqs queues from any region in private EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, amazon-vpc

I am using sqs api(Polling messages, deleting messages, getQueueUrl etc) in private EC2 instance & IAM role attached with sqs policy to it. I have created vpc endpoint to make sqs api work with queues in same region of created vpc endpoint. I also want to use queues from other region as well. Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: You will likely need a nat gateway and access sqs in other regions using their urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AWS Documentation, this is not possible with VPC Endpoints.  You will need to implement a NAT Gateway, as other Regions' Service endpoints are only accessible publicly:

> Endpoints are supported within the same Region only. You cannot create an endpoint between a VPC and a service in a different Region.

Reference: [Interface VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html)